# Recommended way with Git to go back to a previous commit

Tags: git, commit

Hy,

I have some commits in my local repository in GIT(commit1, commit2 and commit3).The remote repository is updated with the last commit3.  Now I noticed the commit2 and commit3 introduces some bugs and I want go back to commit1. I used a reset commit1 but after I cannot push because the head in the local branch is older than the remote branch and git says I need to update so

1. What is the recommended way to do it according to GIT, using reset, checkout...?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are sure you want to destroy this 2 commits in the remote repository and annoying all the devs that already fetch them, you just have to do a force push after the reset you did :

```
git push origin master --force-with-lease
```

If `origin` is your remote and `master` your local branch...

Comment: I have used git reset --hard  commit1 and after what you said but is not other way? Because git reset --hard is considered dangerous. Maybe git checkout commit1 and git push origin master --force-with-lease?

Answer (score 3):

It is safest to use 'git revert' to create a commit4 which undoes the changes 2 and 3. If not, you'll have to use push -f, and then only if the remote server allows it.

Comment: Thanks but how to use git revert and modify the working directory because with git revert you only modify the repository but not the staging area and not the working directory

Comment: Wrong. Git revert modifies the working dir; it makes a commit that puts things back the way they were .